# Looking for a solution that allows Polling but with a workflow

Tags: open-source, polls

I am looking for a solution that allows a polling workflow of sorts. A sample example could be:

- A group of 5 friends are first sent the open ended poll for what places to meet for dinner.
- Assuming that all 5 friends submit 5 different options, the software then creates a poll with those options so it can be voted upon allowing each voter to vote only for options provided by others and not their own option.
- Once this poll has concluded, software declares a winner but in case of a tie for top position another round of poll is created. This continues until a clear winner is established or the polling time runs out in which case it will be a tie and a flip of coin can be simulated to declare the winner.

I am literally looking for something like this if it exists as i could not find anything on google... ideally a bot on rocket.chat or telegram is what I am after. I think self hosted will be good indeed and I don't think I would want to bother with wordpress and such.

Comment: If you are looking for existing web app you can give https://pollunit.com a try. You can create an idea collection, this can be converted to a poll, a poll can be cloned to start again.

Comment: @Markus thanks it does seem to have the option I was hoping for.

Comment: @Izzy I added PollUnit as answer.

Comment: Thanks @Markus! **techbolt:** Please accept the answer, then we can cleanup the remaining comments ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [PollUnit](https://pollunit.com) you can create [idea collections](https://pollunit.com/en/collect-ideas-and-feedback) and [polls](https://pollunit.com/en/voting). A idea collection can be converted into a poll or you allow participants to add options directly to the poll.

A poll/voting can be cloned. If necessary, options can be removed/added and participants can vote again.

PollUnit does not offer a flip of coin in case of a tie. However, when closing a poll, the winner can be chosen. So you could flip a real coin.

Here is a sample image of an idea collection and voting:

[image]
[image]

Disclosure: I work for PollUnit